# Counting number of occurances of a number in a string

Tags: php, string

I want to count the number of occurances of each number in a given string. For eg:-

```
'11 1 2 5 1 2 4 2 7 11 3002 221 3002'
```

This is a string with spaces between the numbers.  I used str_wrd_cnt() and array_count_values() but str_word_cnt() considers only characters in the string.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: @cnicutar - which would not teach the OP to tag properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to split the string into an array of numbers, then count the values. In PHP maybe you'd do something like `array_count_values(explode(' ', '11 1 2 5 1 2 4 2 7 11 3002 221 3002'))`

Comment: This is great! Thanks for your help. This one worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand you very well, but to get max count of these numbers, try this:

```
$string = '11 1 2 5 1 2 4 2 7 11 3002 221 3002';
$exp = explode(" ", $string);
$count = 0;
foreach($exp as $numbers) {
$count+=$numbers;
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

There:

```
function find($str, $number) {
    $start = 0;
    $count = 0;
    while (true) {
        $start = strpos($str, $number, $start);
        if ($start === false)
            break;
        $count++;
        $start++;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo find('11 14 11 12 11', '11');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Three of you helped me in developing my code :)